# Displaying different forms using JQuery slideToggle

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I'm a beginner with JQuery and I wanted to display a hidden log in form and a hidden sign up form using the slide toggle function. The problem that I'm having is that once I click on a link, the form does appear but the link next to it gets pushed as well depending on the width of the form which ruins the look of the entire menu. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

My code for the html part is like this:

```
<!-- Login Starts Here -->
<div id="loginContainer">
    <a href="#" id="loginButton"><span>LOGIN</span><em></em></a>
        <div id="loginBox" style="display:none">                
            <form id="loginForm">
            <!--FORM STUFF-->
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
<!-- Login Ends Here -->
<!-- Sign Up Starts Here -->
<div id="signUpContainer">
    <a href="#" id="signUpButton"><span>Sign Up</span><em></em></a>
        <div id="signUpBox" style="display:none">                
            <form id="signUpForm">
            <!--FORM STUFF-->
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

My code for the JQuery part looks like this:

```
$(function () {
     $('#signUpButton').click(function () {
         $('#signUpBox').slideToggle(200);
         $(this).toggleClass("active");
     });
     $('#loginButton').click(function () {
         $('#loginBox').slideToggle(200);
         $(this).toggleClass("active");
     });
 });
```

I've also made a jsfiddle to better demonstrate the problem that I'm having: 
http://jsfiddle.net/smsyr/3/

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: One option: http://jsfiddle.net/gPLB3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the positioning of the element. If you have a class/id for it already with styles then just add `position: absolute;` to it otherwise you need to make a class/id to add absolute to. Look at the fiddle to show you how it is working.

This also happened because the form is wrapped in a `div`. This element by default is a block element and that will push the second button down according to it's width or height.

```
#loginBox {
  position: absolute;
}
```

If you have more then just two dropdowns then you will want to consider re writing how you have this set up. if you add absolute to all of the forms then they will smash together since they will all align left/top : 0 by default.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/smsyr/5/)

Comment: Ah I see, I had a feeling that it had something to do with the form div. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: No problem mate and best of luck in your site!

Answer (score 0):

change your HTML markup

write :

```
<a href="#" id="loginButton"><span>LOGIN</span><em></em></a>
<a href="#" id="signUpButton"><span>SIGN UP</span><em></em></a>
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/smsyr/4/)

Comment: -1 This is a very sloppy answer. The problem isn't with the order of the a tags or the jquery, it's pertaining to the CSS. This is a solution but not a very well thought out solution.

Comment: Well please do explain and I'll remove my down vote.

Comment: ordering of html elements and css are 100% related. in this case if by changing order of just 1 element we get desired result then there is no point in touching css. positioning of elements needs to be used very carefully.

Comment: I don't disagree that order of html elements and css go hand n hand but this answer is not a "desired" result. Sadly the css has to be touched because of the element being a `div`. That is a block element so it will move other objects around based on the default characteristics of the element. The OP did not want the second menu to align next to the second button and that is caused by the `div`.

Comment: ya I understand that "element being a div. That is a block element so it will move other objects around based on the default characteristics of the element", thats why I pushed singup button along with loginbutton.

Comment: Sadly I can't remove my down vote because it has been to long unless you delete your answer. I'm not saying that your answer has nothing to do with this question but only half of the answer. Best of luck to you though.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your fiddle, so I modified the following CSS style (the result is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/smsyr/6/)):

```
#signUpContainer {
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:'Montserrat', Helvetica;
    float: left;
    width: 230px; /* here */
    background-color: #000;  /* here */
}

#loginContainer {
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:'Montserrat', Helvetica;
    float: left;
    width: 230px;  /*here*/
    background-color: #000;  /*here*/
}
```

I have added two new items in CSS:

```
#loginBox {
    background-color: #FFF;  /* or transparent */
}

#signUpBox {
    background-color: #FFF; /*or transparent*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the update for the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smsyr/7/)...

just added the links outside the forms divs..

```
<div class="something">
    <a href="#" id="signUpButton"><span>SIGN UP</span><em></em></a>
    <a href="#" id="loginButton"><span>LOGIN</span><em></em></a>  
</div>
```

and in the css

```
.something {
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```